# iPhone wheel (of fortune) rotation momentum

Tags: iphone, objective-c, touch, angular-momentum

I'm having difficulties adding momentum to my spinning wheel.
I have this wheel (something like [this](http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/53000/53000,1168924950,2/stock-vector-wheel-of-fortune-room-for-your-text-vector-2494055.jpg)) and I'm rotating it around it's center by using a single touch event.
No problems here, but when the touch (aka drag) ends; I want the wheel to keep it's momentum and ease out it's movement.
Anyone who can give me some pointers, it doesn't necessarily have to be in objective-c.
AS3, javascript or JAVA will also be sufficient.

*** UPDATE (code for rotating the wheel) ***

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        rotation = _startAngle = atan2(384 - touchPoint.y, 512 - touchPoint.x);
    };

    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        rotation = atan2(384 - touchPoint.y, 512 - touchPoint.x);
        rotation = fmod(rotation - _startAngle, M_PI * 2.0f);
        [wheel setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(_circleRotationOffset + rotation)];   
    };

    -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        _circleRotationOffset = fmod(_circleRotationOffset + rotation, M_PI * 2);
    };
```

Comment: How exactly are you handling the rotation? Post some code.

Comment: ^ updated my post w/ the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the momentum to reduce due to friction; friction is a force that's a function of velocity. So technically you've got a differential equation going on. That's not really worth investing too much thought into though, because the solution is probably more easily reached by hand waving.

So: store current angle and current angular velocity. *n* times a second (probably via an `NSTimer` or a `CADisplayLink`) add the angular velocity to the angle, then multiply the angular velocity by something to make it smaller — such as 0.995. Constants closer to 1.0 will make it take longer to slow down; if you go above 1.0 it'll obviously accelerate. This is effectively a form of Euler integration but, again, it's not worth worrying about.

It's possibly also worth putting a minimum cap on angular velocity so that if it drops below, say 0.01 radians/second then you snap it down to 0. That effectively modifies your model of friction slightly to jump from kinetic to static friction at an opportune moment, and acts as a floating point precision buffer zone.

To get initial velocity from a drag you can just work out the vector from the centre of the wheel to the start of the drag, rotate that vector by 90 degrees, do a dot product with that and the drag vector and scale according to distance from the centre.

Comment: Multiply by the fraction and also subtract a small amount.  This will assure that you get to zero in finite time.

Comment: Thanks for heading me in the right direction, I did something similar, but it didn't get the right results. In my answer I used the touchpoints for calculation instead of the (current) rotation

Answer (score 1):

If you are spinning the UIImageView with code like:
`[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotateImage" context:nil];`
`[UIView setAnimationDuration:4.0];`
`wheelImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14159265*5);`
`[UIView commitAnimations];`
You could use `[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];`
This makes it so the animation will start off fast and start to slow down over time.

[Click Here for More info on UIViewAnimationCurve](http://goo.gl/kR6IE)

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is 'extrapolation' or 'momentum'

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get some nice results.
How I did it, should be tweaked more, but this is the basics:

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        rotation = _startAngle = atan2(384 - touchPoint.y, 512 - touchPoint.x);
        [_history removeAllObjects];
    };

    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        [_history insertObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()], @"time", [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touchPoint], @"point", [NSNumber numberWithFloat: _circleRotationOffset + rotation], @"rotation", nil] atIndex:0];
        if ([_history count] == 3) {
            [_history removeLastObject];
        }

        rotation = atan2(384 - touchPoint.y, 512 - touchPoint.x) - _startAngle;
        [circleImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(_circleRotationOffset +         rotation)]; 
    };

    -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {   
        CGPoint tp = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
        _circleRotationOffset += rotation;

        NSDictionary *lo = [_history lastObject];
        CGPoint pp = [[lo objectForKey:@"point"] CGPointValue];
        double timeDif = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - [[lo objectForKey:@"time"] doubleValue];
        float lastRotation = [[lo objectForKey:@"rotation"] floatValue];

        // Calculate strength
        float dist = sqrtf(((pp.x - tp.x) * (pp.x - tp.x)) + ((pp.y - tp.y) * (pp.y - tp.y)));
        float strength = MIN(1.0f, dist / 80.0f) * (timeDif / .025) * M_PI;

        float p = _circleRotationOffset;
        float dif = _circleRotationOffset - lastRotation;
        BOOL inc = dif > 0;
        if (dif > 3 || dif < -3) { // Some correction
            inc = !inc;
        }

        if (inc) {
            _circleRotationOffset += strength;  
        } else {
            _circleRotationOffset -= strength;
        }

        [circleImage.layer removeAllAnimations];
        CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
        animation.duration = MAX(strength / 2.5, 1.0f);
        animation.cumulative = YES;
        animation.repeatCount = 1;
        animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:          
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:p], 
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat: _circleRotationOffset], nil]; 
        animation.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0], 
                      [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil]; 
        animation.timingFunctions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut], nil];
        animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
        animation.delegate = self;
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

        [circleImage.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotate"];
    };
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more what's going on here? _circleRotationOffset is that the angle from 0 to the finger and you're adding the small rotation from finger to finger ? A little more descriptive would be great if you don't mind.

Comment: `_circleRotationOffset` would be the 'current' rotatation of the wheel. Which will start at '0' and will be update throughout the touches. All with all the solution to this problem is calculating the momentum.

Comment: But the current angle shouldn't be important. I've written a gesture recognizer, for a one finger rotation around a centre point. When I end, I can check the delegate conforms to my optional "continue rotation" protocol, if so I pass along a velocity and direction. The delegate, say the view controller, now has a velocity (radians/sec) and direction (clockwise/anticlockwise). I'm trying to use CAKeyframeAnimation to achieve a momentum rotation like you. Having a hard time with the CA. Don't want to post another question as it's duplicate of yours. So trying to use what's here. tips?

Comment: what is 382 or 512?